# On a Mac how do I remove Openpyxl when it has already been installed before using sudo pip install openpyxl?

Tags: python, pip, openpyxl

Previously openpyxl was installed on a mac. I need to remove it or fix it because it seems to be broken and then I want to reinstall it. Every time i try `easy_install -m openpyxl` it doesn't work or doing a new install doesn't work. I receive a syntax error.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py:208: Warning: 'as' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/runpy.py", line 88, in run_module
    code = loader.get_code(mod_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pkgutil.py", line 283, in get_code
    self.code = self._get_delegate().get_code()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/pkgutil.py", line 275, in get_code
    self.code = compile(source, self.filename, 'exec')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 208
    except PipError as exc:
```

I  am a def newbie when it comes to not only coding but python.

Comment: Important info about this mac im on is MAC OS X Version 10.6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try uninstalling it first using pip with the command `sudo pip uninstall openpyxl`.

Having said that, it looks like the error is because you're using Python 2.5 and "as" became a reserved keyword in Python 2.6. Your best bet is to install a new version of Python and install openpyxl, or find a version of openpyxl and pip that supports Python 2.5.

Reading up on openpyxl, it looks like the last version that supported Python 2.5 is version 1.7.0. See the package's [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/1.8.5). And the version of `pip` that supports Python 2.5 is [1.3.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.3.1).

So first you need to downgrade pip. The version of pip is FUBARed, so you will have to install pip 1.3.1 from source. Download it from the [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.3.1), unpack it and go into the folder with the file `setup.py`. Then run `python setup.py build` followed by `sudo python setup.py install`. This should have downgraded `pip`.

Next install openpyxl version 1.7.0 `sudo pip install openpyxl==1.7.0`.

Comment: is there an easy way to install python in the mac terminal or just go to the website?

Comment: First try installing version 1.7.0 of openpyxl as that's the last version to support Python 2.5. That should fix your problem. Next, if you want to install the latest version of Python the best thing to do is to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh). Once that's installed, it's as easy as typing `brew install python` in the terminal and you'll have the latest version of Python.

Comment: Still says syntax error for me when i tried to install openpyxl 1.7.0 Also i did try installing homebrew, however it says "failed during: usr/local/bin/brew/tap homebrew/core" "You must: brew install git" So i do that and I keep getting "You must: brew install git"

Comment: Happens when i try python setup.py build. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: We strongly recommend that you use a virtual environment for any projects so that you don't have to worry too much about the system Python. That said, I'd strongly recommend you install Python using the installer from http://www.python.org. This should get you a working version of pip. You can learn to use Homebrew (or MacPorts which I prefer) later.

Comment: @Dorilds You need to download `pip-1.3.1.tar.gz` from the PyPI page linked in the answer. Then you need to extract that archive, and from the terminal you need to navigate to the directory where the source files are extracted. Then `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` will work.

Comment: Thanks i got it all except now i got a NoSSLError

Comment: Where is that error coming from? There shouldn't be SSL involved in installing `pip` or `openpyxl`.